# Am I dumb? What's wrong with this one line for an auto hotkey script

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make this very simple script auto-click for Roblox, but when I run the program it says "parameter #3 invalid, specifically ahk_pid 13636" despite this being the correct window title being displayed in [Window Spy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHsKa.png).

```
F7::
Loop, 5 ControlClick, x400 y375, ahk_pid 13636, Roblox, Left, 1

F8:: ExitApp
```

[SciTE Debug Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkwHS.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to pass in all those arguments to the loop command, as opposed using the `ControlClick` command at any point. And you're also using the `WinText` parameter incorrectly (you just want to ignore that parameter altogether).

This would be the correct way:
(`{ }` are optional for one line statements)

```
F7::
    Loop, 5
    {
        ControlClick, x400 y375, ahk_pid 13636, , , , NA
    }
return

F8:: ExitApp
```

I also added in the `NA` option because it's [recommended](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm#Reliability) if it works for the desired window.
If the option would cause it not to work, remove it.

Also remember that control clicking is always pretty much a hit or miss.
If it works, great, if not, don't be surprised.

Comment: I made a script for clicking and it worked excellently when Notepad was the active window for example, but only every 10th click or so showed up when Roblox was the active window.  In the end, I set it for a 1 second loop and Roblox saw a click every 10 seconds or so.  I've heard other people say that TinyTask works well.

Comment: Thank you for your help and you basically solved my issue, although I couldn't get ControlClick to work for Roblox. I'll expand on your example greatly though and look for improvements and find an alternative method for this game.